# how to keep a delay line by line in web browser

Tags: c#

hi i want to keep a delay to line by line for 5 seconds .
I used following code but it is not working.

```
 private void button3_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
 {
        textBox4.Text = textBox3.Text;
        string[] groups = textBox4.Text.Split('\n');

        webBrowser1.Navigate("https://mbasic.facebook.com/groups/516524655403741");
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        webBrowser1.Navigate("https://mbasic.facebook.com/groups/548734261950831");
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        webBrowser1.Navigate("https://mbasic.facebook.com/groups/202669939887242");
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        webBrowser1.Navigate("https://mbasic.facebook.com/groups/259531940895144");
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```

After executing this code. it got **20** seconds to redirect to last website...

But i want to run all website within **5** seconds to **5** seconds..
Please fix my issue.

Comment: I don't think anyone understands what you mean by "within 5 seconds to 5 seconds"

Comment: 1st go to the  https://mbasic.facebook.com/groups/516524655403741 
then wait 5 seconds 
then go to the 2nd one  https://mbasic.facebook.com/groups/516524655403741 ,.... etc

Comment: I see. You must do your waiting in the [`Navigated`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigated(v=vs.110).aspx) event because that method is not synchronous.

Comment: is there are keyword call    wait    or something?

Comment: There are examples at the link I provided on how to wire up the event.

Comment: There are very few good reasons to ever use `Thread.Sleep`. You need to understand how the UI thread works and why your approach won't work.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not the webbrowser client you are using. The problem is that you are blocking the "GUI thread" by a total of 20 seconds. During these 20 seconds now GUI updates will take place until your `button3_Click()` method finishes.

Rewrite your code that a different thread is executing the `Sleep()` and `Navigate()` methods. You might need to use the [`Dispatcher.Invoke()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke(v=vs.110).aspx) method to get access to the "GUI thread" again, when you want to update the GUI from a non-"GUI thread".